# Purpose of C function generated by matlab is unknown

Tags: c++, c, matlab, math, signal-processing

Could someone please help me understand what this function is doing? 
I am guessing its doing some kind of exponentiation. I searched on google for the name it seems it comes from some C code generated by matlab. 
Does anyone know exactly what this function is supposed to do?
What could SNF stand for?
Thank you.

```
double rt_powd_snf(double u0, double u1)
{
  double y;
  double d0;
  double d1;
  if (isnan(u0) || isnan(u1))
  {
    y = NAN;
  }
  else
  {
    d0 = fabs(u0);
    d1 = fabs(u1);
    if (isinf(u1))
    {
      if (d0 == 1.0)
      {
        y = 1.0;
      }
      else if (d0 > 1.0)
      {
        if (u1 > 0.0)
        {
          y = INFINITY;
        }
        else
        {
          y = 0.0;
        }
      }
      else if (u1 > 0.0)
      {
        y = 0.0;
      }
      else
      {
        y = INFINITY;
      }
    }
    else if (d1 == 0.0)
    {
      y = 1.0;
    }
    else if (d1 == 1.0)
    {
      if (u1 > 0.0)
      {
        y = u0;
      }
      else
      {
        y = 1.0 / u0;
      }
    }
    else if (u1 == 2.0)
    {
      y = u0 * u0;
    }
    else if ((u1 == 0.5) && (u0 >= 0.0))
    {
      y = sqrt(u0);
    }
    else if ((u0 < 0.0) && (u1 > floor(u1)))
    {
      y = NAN;
    }
    else
    {
      y = pow(u0, u1);
    }
  }

  return y;
}
```

Comment: It's a function for raising one double to the power of another. It's got code for many special cases, and defaults to a regular `pow` if the don't apply.\

Comment: @ThomasJager Please make this an answer for yellow_watermelon to mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function raises one `double` to the power of another `double`.

You can see this by the `pow` call at the bottom:

```
y = pow(u0, u1);
```

It also handle various special cases, cleanly handling not-a-number and infinite input, and efficiently handling special values.

The `powd` means that it's a power function that uses doubles. From the documentation, `_snf` means that it can handle non-finite numbers. The `rt_` prefix comes from the configuration variable **MAT-file variable name modifier**. I'd guess that this stands for "runtime", but that's not founded.

In the code, `d0` and `d1` are the absolute (negatives become positive) versions of the inputs `u0` and `u1`. The result is in `y`.

---

Going through the code:

- If either the base or the exponent are NAN

  - Return NAN
- If the exponent is infinite

  - If the absolute base is 1.0

    - Return 1.0
  - If the absolute base is greater than 1.0

    - If the exponent is positive (infinity)

      - Return INFINITY
    - Else the exponent is negative (infinity)

      - Return 0.0
  - Else the absolute base is less than 1.0

    - If the exponent is positive (infinity)

      - Return 0.0
    - Else the exponent is negative (infinity)

      - Return INFINITY
- If the absolute exponent is 0.0

  - Return 1.0
- If the absolute exponent is 1.0

  - If the exponent is positive (1.0)

    - Return the base
  - Else the exponent is negative (1.0)

    - Return 1.0 / base
- If the exponent is 2.0

  - Return the base times itself
- If the exponent is 0.5 and the base is non-negative

  - Return the square root of the base
- If the base is negative and the exponent is not an integer

  - Return NAN
- Else the case is not special

  - Return the result of `pow(u0, u1)`